# Find and remove unique values within a phrase across multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Have hit a complete roadblock on this one - I am trying to remove unique values within a Product Name column by comparing multiple cells. The end result is to create a logical 'category' in column B for each row, something like this:

Category Result Example:
[image]

Where I am coming unstuck is because there may be duplicates at various points in the string that clash e.g "Shirt Blue" in A2 & "Shirt Blue" in A4.

What might save me is the first 2 words, or roughly 10 characters, of 'like' products are always identical across cells so in essence I am trying to find a formula that will check if the first 10 characters are identical and then remove any remaining unique values from all cells in the range

Comment: I think what you actually want is to create a blacklist of words to exclude, such as "Blue", "Red", "XL", etc and then strip them out, as there is no guarantee that the first x amount of characters or words will be sufficient.  To remove singleton characters such as "S", you can append a space to the end of the Product Name and search for " S ".

Comment: Thanks @iamdave - unfortunately I have provided a simplified version of my data set for the example, in actual fact the full set is around 20k products with wildly different 'unique' values outside of size + colour so I think what you suggest would be too time consuming to implement?

Comment: I agree with @iamdave.  I don't think there is any way to implement this without a blacklist.  Perhaps generate a list of unique words, and then examine that list to figure out your blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

This will not really do everything you need, but if you just want to pick up the first 2 words, you can find everything before the second space using this formula:
`=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ", A1,FIND(" ", A1)+1)-1)`

To increase the number of words to look for, you just need to add more `FIND`s in, like so:
`=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ", A1, FIND(" ", A1,FIND(" ", A1)+1)+1)-1)`